# Connecting two messy mesh together the easy way?

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode, vertices, topology

i have two piece of a sofa right here

[image]

[image]

[image]

the problem is that the topology is a mess, and the limit of the two mesh are not the same.

what i want is two thing:

- **aligning the two lines of the edges of the sofa together smoothly ?**
- **having a fast way to adjust the topology, for a coherent vertex
  connection ?**

all of this witouth waisting time manually moving each vertex to each other, there's just oo much verticles, i need to find a way to automate this process ? any idea ? or addons ?

here is the file 
https://we.tl/t-9kFVWQb25D

---

*edit*

*i see that the mirror option is a really good solution for this case because the two cushions are somewhat similar, but what if it's not ?*

Comment: Have you tried to use a mirror modifier on one of these two parts (with clipping option)?

Comment: I'd suggest doing a poisson mesh reconstruction in MeshLab, then retopo with Instant Meshes. That would probably be the fastest way.

Comment: Have you tried "Bridge edge loops", then smoothing the topology in sculpt mode?

Comment: Mirror is not so bad (with few vertices corrections) https://we.tl/t-AXl23hPktM

Comment: @lemon thanks for the mirror advice, it could work here because the meshes are similar, but what if they are not ?

Comment: If they are not, try what said rjg or Leander... Don't know if you've seen it but the corrected mesh is in the link of my previous comment.

Comment: Leave a small gap between the 2 meshes. If vertex positions and number of verts is similar then bridge edge loops should work. If it creates bad geometry, then make 2 bridge faces manually. You can then fill the gap between two bridge faces by selecting it and making a face using F and CTRL+T for triangulate.